# Match numpy digitize bin column names to input list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to convert the column names output by numpy back into more readable names.

Challenges: Columns do not come out in order after long process of binning lots of data. I cannot seem to get a good match for all column names.

The Data:

```
# input bin list
bins_2_bin = [-6. , -5.4, -4.8, -4.2, -3.6, -3. , -2.4, -1.8, -1.2, -0.6,  0. ,
        0.6,  1.2,  1.8,  2.4,  3. ,  3.6,  4.2,  4.8,  5.4,  6. ]

output_column_names = ['[-0.6000000000000005-0.0]', '[-1.2000000000000002--0.6000000000000005]', '[-1.7999999999999998--1.2000000000000002]', '[-2.4000000000000004--1.7999999999999998]', '[-3.0--2.4000000000000004]', '[-3.6--3.0]', '[-4.2--3.6]', '[-4.8--4.2]', '[-5.4--4.8]', '[-6.0--5.4]', '[0.0-0.5999999999999996]', '[0.5999999999999996-1.1999999999999993]', '[1.1999999999999993-1.7999999999999998]', '[1.7999999999999998-2.4000000000000004]', '[2.4000000000000004-3.0]', '[3.0-3.5999999999999996]', '[3.5999999999999996-4.199999999999999]', '[4.199999999999999-4.799999999999999]', '[4.799999999999999-5.4]', '[5.4-6.0]']

desired_names = ['-6.0:-5.4', '-5.4:-4.8', '-4.8:-4.2', '-4.2:-3.6', '-3.6:-3.0', '-3.0:-2.4', '-2.4:-1.8', '-1.8:-1.2', '-1.2:-0.6', '-0.6:0.0', '0.0:0.6', '0.6:1.2', '1.2:1.8', '1.8:2.4', '2.4:3.0', '3.0:3.6', '3.6:4.2', '4.2:4.8', '4.8:5.4', '5.4:6.0']

# my best attempt at creating a dictionary to rename the columns
names = {}

for bad_name in output_columns_names:
    temp = bad_name[1:6].rstrip('-')

    for good_name in desired_names:

        if temp in good_name[1:5]:
            names[bad_name] = good_name
```

But this misses some matches. I am not sure how I would improve the matching.

```
names = {'[-3.0--2.4000000000000004]': '[-3.0:-2.4]', '[-3.6--3.0]': '[-3.6:-3.0]', '[-4.2--3.6]': '[-4.2:-3.6]', '[-4.8--4.2]': '[-4.8:-4.2]', '[-5.4--4.8]': '[-5.4:-4.8]', '[-6.0--5.4]': '[-6.0:-5.4]'}

# missing keys
['[-0.6000000000000005-0.0]', '[-1.2000000000000002--0.6000000000000005]', '[-1.7999999999999998--1.2000000000000002]', '[-2.4000000000000004--1.7999999999999998]', '[0.0-0.5999999999999996]', '[0.5999999999999996-1.1999999999999993]', '[1.1999999999999993-1.7999999999999998]', '[1.7999999999999998-2.4000000000000004]', '[2.4000000000000004-3.0]', '[3.0-3.5999999999999996]', '[3.5999999999999996-4.199999999999999]', '[4.199999999999999-4.799999999999999]', '[4.799999999999999-5.4]', '[5.4-6.0]']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around more and widening my mind. I discovered regex can get me pretty close.  Just need to replace the middle '-' with a colon (':').

```
def convert_bin_label(label):

    # remove brackets
    label = label.strip('[]')

    simpledec = re.compile(r"\d*\.\d+")

    def mround(match):
        return "{:.1f}".format(float(match.group()))

    return re.sub(simpledec, mround, label)


for _ in output_column_names:
    print(convert_bin_label(_))

Outputs:
-0.6-0.0
-1.2--0.6
-1.8--1.2
-2.4--1.8
-3.0--2.4
-3.6--3.0
-4.2--3.6
-4.8--4.2
-5.4--4.8
-6.0--5.4
0.0-0.6
0.6-1.2
1.2-1.8
1.8-2.4
2.4-3.0
3.0-3.6
3.6-4.2
4.2-4.8
4.8-5.4
5.4-6.0
```